# Odoo 14 - how to change display name of "product_template_id" field ONLY in sale module?

Tags: odoo, product, inventory

I am trying to figure out solution of the problem mentioned in title.

In sale module, after I pressed "Add a product" when creating sale order and chose a product in "product_template_id" field, I want to display internal reference ONLY.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgMTF.png)

Here is what I found. display_name of product here is controlled by "product.product". Once I make changes in product.product, display_name of products in other module (like purchase, accounting) will also be changed, which is not what I want.

So how can I do this?

Thank you.

I tried to override name_get function in "product.product". But display name will be changed globally, which is not what I want.

Hope someone can lend me a helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the product [name_get](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/product/models/product.py#L452-L454) function, you will see that you can set the `display_default_code` value to `False` through the context to hide the default code.

```py
code = self._context.get('display_default_code', True) and d.get('default_code', False) or False
if code:
    name = '[%s] %s' % (code,name)
```

You can implement the same logic to hide the name field.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

End up I used odoo javascript to do that.